# Spring Tool Suite - Error

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to create a project in STS 3.7.1. When I tried creating a spring starter project, it is giving me an error something like this...

IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://start.spring.io/starter.zip?name=hello-boot&groupId=org.test&artifactId=hello-boot&version=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT&description=hello+boot&packageName=org.test.demo&type=maven-project&packaging=jar&javaVersion=1.8&language=java&bootVersion=1.2.7.RELEASE&dependencies=web

I tried creating the project with different name, re-installing. No success. Can anybody suggest what is the problem? I am using 1.8 JDK for this version.

[image: popup]

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a HTTP 403 Forbidden from the spring.io HTTP server. I can access your URL and download the archive - maybe you have a restrictive proxy or firewall in your way?

If you can access it from your browser, just download and unzip the archive and open it inside STS.

Comment: Thanks localhorst...How would I know that it has restrictive proxy / firewall? So far developing applications in Ecplise never had these kind of problems. So I am unaware of this.

Comment: It's just a wild guess for this issue. If you don't have anything like that in your network, it's possible that a proxy is set inside the Java configuration (Control Panel -> Java -> Network Settings).

It's also possible that spring.io just gave you a 403 due to an overload of their server while Eclipse made that request.

Comment: Hi Localhorst, I guess it is a proxy problem. No matter what I tried changing the problem persists. I tried the same thing on a different computer and it works flowless. I don't know where the problem is? Can you help?